# Unterschied zwischen Handelsgewerbe, Gewerbe und Gewerbebetrieb

Tags: difference

Es klingt für mich, dass alle diese Wörter ähnliche Bedeutung haben, aber für mich ist es wichtig diese Unterschied zu verstehen.

Also nach Duden:

- der Ge­wer­be­be­trieb - gewerblicher Betrieb (Fabrik, Betrieb);
- das Gewerbe - Gesamtheit der [produzierenden] kleinen und mittleren Betriebe, [Handels]unternehmen; Bereich der gewerblichen Tätigkeit;
- das Handelsgewerbe - Gewerbe, das sich dem Handel in Form von Kauf und Verkauf von Gütern widmet; kaufmännisches Gewerbe.

Comment: Und was ist daran unklar?

Comment: Also ich verstehe die Frage auch nicht... die drei Definitionen beantworten doch schon die Frage: Gewerbe = Überbegriff alle Unternehmen, Gewerbebetrieb = Eines der Unternehmen aus dem ersten Begriff, Handelsgewerbe = Eine spezielle Art des Gewerbes, erneut ein Überbegriff, aber halt eine Untermenge von Gewerbe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gewerbe

> Handelsgewerbe
>
> Metallgewerbe
>
> Textilgewerbe

Meistens wird es einfach "Handel", "Metall" oder "Textil" genannt.
Z.B. "Im Handel verdient man wenig."

Gewerbebetrieb

> Media Markt
>
> Humanic
>
> Tesla

Hier geht es dann um tatsächliche Fabriken, Firmen und so weiter. Nach meinem Verständnis geht es hier um bestimmte Standorte dieser Firmen, nicht die Firmenstandorte im allgemeinen.

Comment: Zusätzliche Information, die ich gefunden habe: 
Gewerbe ist eine Tätigkeit, die auf Dauer angelegt, einen Gewinnerzielungsabsicht hat, nach außen gerichtet und selbständig ist. 

Wenn ein Gewerbe kaufmännisch organisiert sein muss, ist es ein Handelsgewerbe.